# Build a custom CMD FOR DIR "File Not Found" message for a Windows 10 batch file

Tags: batch, cmd.exe

Windows 10 64-bit.

The 101st time you run your batch file, it spits out this message:
"File Not Found".

It takes you so long to trace down the source of the message you decide to write a custom message, but you do not know how to use escape characters, redirection, pipes, conditional execution, if/then/else, and nested parentheses in FOR commands, or, for that matter, the best way to go about it.

The commands have been severely edited for brevity and clarity.

The command that generated the message:

```
FOR /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('DIR /b "*.mov"') do (SET /A COUNT+=1 &@ren "%%a" "%%~na-!COUNT!.mov")
```

If there are no `*.mov` file(s), the DIR command outputs "File Not Found".

These are the alternatives I have so far.  Please post your own solution, comments or answers.

`DIR /b "*.mov" | FINDSTR /i /n /c:"File Not Found">NUL && echo No video to process. || FOR /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('DIR /b "*.mov"') do (SET /A COUNT+=1 &@ren "%%a" "%%~na-!COUNT!.mov")`

```
DIR /b "*.mov" | FINDSTR /i /n /c:"File Not Found">NUL && (echo No video to process. &GOTO :continue)
FOR /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('DIR /b "*.mov"') do (SET /A COUNT+=1 &@ren "%%a" "%%~na-!COUNT!.mov")
:continue
```

`FOR /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('DIR /b "*.mov" 2^>nul ^|^|(echo No video to process^)') do if "%%a"=="No video to process" (echo No video to process) else for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir /b /a-d "*.mov"') do (SET /A COUNT+=1 &@ren "%%a" "%%~na-!COUNT!.mov")`

Comment: You'd have to capture the error in the script and echo your desired message instead. Could you please use more clear language in place of "atom bomb" and "spitwad" too? It's not super clear what you are trying to convey with these.

Comment: If you're on Windows 10, why not use PowerShell? It's worth learning.

Answer (score 0):

- Without taking into account a failure of the dir could have other reasons
  (rights/nonexisting drive etc.)

Cmd line:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %a in ('dir /b "*.mov" 2^>nul ^|^|(echo:No video to process^)') do @echo %a
```

Batch file:

```
@Echo off
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('
    dir /b "*.mov" 2^>nul ^|^|(echo:No video to process^)
') do echo %%a
```

Comment: I don't see the use case, if a file doesn't exist the only appropriate reaction is IMO to not try a rename at all, which is sufficiently suppressed with appending `2^>NUL` to the dir inside a `for /f`.

Comment: Then the redirection `2^>NUL` and the [conditional execution](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html) on fail `||` will do nothing. With the `Ren` you'll get an error message because it tries to ren the error msg as a file which doesn't exist.

Comment: My original question was poorly written.  I originally said the command that generated the message was: `for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('DIR /b "*.mov"') do @echo %%a` but in fact the command that generated the message was: `FOR /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('DIR /b "*.mov"') do @REN "%%a" "1.mov"`
 If the command is: `FOR /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('DIR /b "*.mov"') do @REN "%%a" "1.mov"` your answer fails if *.mov exists.

Comment: Please reread my above 1st comment and simply use `FOR /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('DIR /b "*.mov" 2^>NUL') do @REN "%%a" "1.mov"` which won't let an error msg pass to the ren command.

Comment: Your answer works if the command is: `for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('DIR /b "*.mov"') do @echo %%a`.  Thanks for taking the time.